# Qt, mysql как узнать про обновление в таблице?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Решил добавить проверку в код загрузки данных из таблицы - "а нужно ли обновлять". Собрал следующий "велосипед":

```
 QSqlQuery query;
 query.exec("show table status from "+base);

 while(query.next() && query.value(0).toString()!=table) {}

 if (query.value(12).toString() != updatecheck || query.value(12).toString()=="")
 {
 // ... и пошла загрузка
```

С данным методом не особенно радует запрос на отображение информации по всем таблицам, плюс на некоторых серверах `update_time` просто не фиксируется и поле остается пустым всегда.

Какие еще методы существуют для решения этой задачи?

Метод по `id` последнего обновления: если обновили два раза одну и ту же уже имеющуюся запись, то загрузки не будет?

Можно по заранее установленному триггеру, но это значит, что он должен быть, плюс, триггеры притормаживают работу БД в целом. Это так?

Comment: А если бы у вас был postgres, все сложилось бы иначе.